# What caused the fall of the Zhou dynasty?

Tags: ancient-history, china

The Zhou dynasty was the longest dynasty, yet in the end they created the [Warring States Period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period) why?

I have read [Wikipedia:Zhou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty), but I don't understand it well.

Comment: Have you checked the Wikipedia page for the Zhou dynasty?

Comment: I have but I don't understand it well.

Comment: You might find the Wikipedia page on the [Spring and Autumn Period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period) gives more detail on the decline of the Zhou dynasty as power shifted to regional lords.

Comment: Will do Thanks! @Steve Bird!

Comment: Please move the comments into the question. Questions where OP makes comments are more likely to be closed and less likely to get an answer.  The question should contain all you know.  Edit the question to address comments, and then flag the comments for deletion (for example, this one....)

Comment: Sorry! I'm new here so i'm learning slowly and steadily

Comment: No worries, we all have to start somewhere. It would help, though, if you explained why you don't find the Wiki article helpful. Summarize what it says and then you can see what is not said that is still perplexing. Or if there's something in there that is confusing, ask about that. Being as specific as possible will yield you the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

The Zhou Dynasty was not a dynasty like the later dynasties. It's actually inaccurate to use the word dynasty to describe Zhou. It didn't have a centralized government. It didn't have an emperor who was the Son of Heaven and was both the head of the state and the government with real powers. The kings of Zhou were more like the heads of the smaller states and was honored only as a figure head. They didn't have the actual rule in running the governments of the small states.

Zhou fell simply for one reason. The loyalty of the dukes and earls toward the king was no longer as strong as before. Some of the states became too powerful that the king had truly become just a nominal figure head. Eventually the dukes and earls saw no reason to even bother to regard the king as a figure head. They declared themselves kings. For a long time, the king reigned only in name only. Later, even the name was considered a nuisance by the dukes and earls who had real power.

The first dynasty in real sense was Qin, which first established the title of Emperor and had actual rule over all the former states, which had now become provinces.

Comment: Adding a source or two would improve your answer. Thank you.